# Why is the OS X modal-view-in-window animation upside-down?

Tags: macos, core-animation

On recent OS X (attached animation is from Mavericks), the modal view appearing in window animates upside down until completely visible. Then it flips to normal position.

http://youtu.be/J_39Zn1kqvQ

UPDATED: Because this is known bug.

Comment: Have you tried standing on your head? in all seriousness, you would need to show code for anyone to begin to explain what is going on with that.

Comment: Of course I've tried THAT! :o) I believe the code is not publicly available, otherwise I would definitely do so .o)

Comment: Apple has reviewed my filed bug as being duplicate, therefore this is a known bug and should change in future.

Comment: Apple has fixed it. It doesn't happen anymore in beta 2 of the upcoming system.